# Looking for non expensive ways to acquire GIS skills

Tags: geolocation, mapping, gis, geospatial

For the past few years I have been taking all of ESRI's free Moocs but I want to get more hands on a creative experience without having to shell out thousands of dollars to take the courses and certifications. Working with maps and especially the idea of bringing new eyes to existing and worsening problems is a life long goal of mine. Any help would be appreciated, The Moocs just give a basic overview of the software functionality and there's not much room for creativity or to work on problems dear to me. If anybody could direct me to some legit resources I will owe you my life. I am currently learning Python which I know will help with the customization of functions and whatnot, but I must admit I'm more on the beginner's side now.

Comment: As all programming: you acquire skills by doing something. Check e.g. QGIS to have a free GIS (GIS notions are not much different to ESRI), you can do also much direct in Python. There are plenty of open data, and documentation. Try to visualize something interesting. And maybe to publish on social media, and go to next project. -- In any case your question is off-topic to this site.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for the help. Which would be a more applicable forum for a question like this';